# I can't insert a node into this doubly linked list, probable segfault

Tags: c, list, pointers, crash, segmentation-fault

I need to develop a doubly linked list in which I can't specify my *prev and *next pointers, they have to be *A and *B, because they may assume each others functions as I tamper with the list. It is probably called a symmetric list in english.

I am having trouble inserting a node in this list. The program crashes (probably a segfault), and I don't know why, because I did use a special case for when the list is empty (if(atual == NULL)). The program is not over yet, there is more to implemente, so don't mind the stuff inside the switch that you don't see implemented yet. One more thing: each node has *A or *B to go along the list. That is why I check which one is looking back, in order to use the other one to go forward.

Sample input:

> i  0  1.2
>
> i  1  2.3
>
> i  2  3.4

Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct no {
    double num;
    struct no *A;
    struct no *B;
} no;

typedef struct lista {
    no *cabo;
    no *rabo;
} lista;

lista* criar(void) {
    lista *L = malloc(sizeof(lista));
    L->cabo = NULL;
    L->rabo = NULL;
    return L;
}

void inserir(lista *L, int posicao, double num) { //testar se funciona e verificar com pad se eh o melhor modo.
    no *novo = malloc(sizeof(no));
    no *atual, *aux;
    atual = L->cabo;
    aux = NULL;
    char ref;
    int i;
    if (atual == NULL) { //a lista nao tem elementos
        novo->A = L->cabo; //inserindo primeiro elemento, que tem contato tanto com a cabeca quanto com o rabo
        novo->B = L->rabo;
        L->cabo = novo;
        L->rabo = novo;
        return;
    }
    for (i = 0; i != posicao; i++) {
        if (atual->A == aux) { //entao A aponta para tras. Para prosseguir uso B.
            aux = atual;
            atual = atual->B;
            ref = 'B';  //o no para onde aux aponta tem seu proximo em B
        }
        else {
            aux = atual;
            atual = atual->A;
            ref = 'A';  //o no para onde aux aponta tem seu proximo em A
        }
    }
    if(ref == 'B') {
        novo->B = aux->B;
        aux->B = novo;
        if (atual->A == aux) {
            atual->A = novo;
        }
        else {
            atual->B = novo;
        }
        novo->A = aux;
    }   
    else if(ref == 'A') {
        novo->B = aux->A;
        aux->A = novo;
        if (atual->A == aux) {
            atual->A = novo;
        }
        else {
            atual->B = novo;
        }
        novo->A = aux;
    }
}

void reverter(lista *L, int inicio, int fim) {
    
}
int main(void) {
    
    lista *L = criar();
    char comando;
    int posicao, inicio, fim;
    double num;
    while(1) {
        scanf("%c", &comando);
        if(comando == 't') break;
        switch(comando) {
            case 'i' :  scanf("%d", &posicao);
                        scanf("%lf", &num);
                        inserir(L, posicao, num);
                        break;
            //case 'p' :    imprimir(L);
                        break;
            case 'v' :  scanf("%d", &inicio);
                        scanf("%d", &fim);
                        reverter(L, inicio, fim);
                        break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (atual = NULL)`  --> `if (atual == NULL)`

Comment: "I can't specify my *prev and *next pointers, they have to be *A and *B, because they may assume each others functions as I tamper with the list" - What? Just use the common names, don't try being creative at the cost of readability! (And don't use all-uppercase names for anything else than macros and enum-constants)

Comment: @Olaf
You don't understand, I am not being creative. I need A and B because sometimes A will be prev and other times it will be next. That's what I said about the list being symmetric. Did you read the whole thing?

Comment: @Olaf
Hey! Thanks for the observation, you are correct. However, I have changed it and it still does not work.

Comment: Did you use a debugger? At a minimum it will tell you which line caused the seg fault and that is the *minimum* debugging info you should share with us.

Comment: _"However, I have changed it and it still does not work."_  You are learning about doubly linked lists, and you don't fully understand how variables truly work...the variable name doesn't even matter! I believe you are in serious need of a [C book companion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  This will help you throughout your ventures into the C programming language, and is a great help at times.  Good luck!